Odd error with keyboard on Ubuntu 24.04
I have an odd bug with my keyboard deactivating at random moments and each push of a button activates several options on the page I am frozen rather than typing a letter.
When the bug happens while on the Terminal instead of selecting strings of characters, I can only select squares (image 1).
Furthermore, it is impossible to select a Tab, It just adds new Tabs to my selection while left-clicking on them (orange highlight image 2).
Is anyone familiar with this bug? Did it happen to anyone else?
I use this OS:
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble



Sorry for the late answer , Today I encountered the same problem with Ubuntu 24.04 , after rebooting everything seems to work fine, we'll see later..
